# C# MVVM Handling and Passing UserID to different Models and ViewModels

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

My current implementation of passing `UserID` in my application is through the constructor.

i.e. `SomeObject s = new SomeObject(userID)`

Where in there is a code behind that does things based on the userID. The userID is further keep tracked by adding another property named "CurrentUser", however this seems to be a dirty solution as I have to implement it to all ViewModels and it seems to violate the "DRY" concept.

The second approach I have in mind is creating a public static variable on my `MainWindowViewModel` where all my other models can refer to it as `MainWindowViewModel.CurrentUser`.

Is one of the two approach the correct way to do this or is there a better approach that i don't know about?

Comment: how about having a public static class where your current user property is stored? Something like implementing it in a `ViewModelLocator` or `App` class would be one solution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to carefully analyze up front what you want to achieve with your application. Are you happy with there only ever being one selected client? Or will you need to have multiple clients being viewed or edited at a time (i.e. you have an MDI style app)?

Going with the single client approach is easy, you can implement the global property bag as already mentioned in other answers. But I will advise caution: if you build your app on the assumption there will only ever be one selected client it becomes a real PITA to try to refactor to make it multi-client capable. Using a centralized property bag or "session service" like this is indeed decoupling state from the VM, but the centralized service can still turn into a monstrosity over time and you build up too much dependence on it.

If you do want to go the multi-client route, then you are on the right track - but instead of passing a client identifier in on the constructor, pass (inject) the entire client data object. The chances are that you already have most of the client details available from the piece of UI that invokes the client oriented VM, so pass it in and save having to make another trip to your database to get the details.

Comment: Yes I want a multi-client app although it is also acceptable to do the single client approach. Also yes I do pass the entire object but for reason of clarity in the question I was specific with the UserID part.  

Just to clarify, are you saying it is ok to pass the "user" object to the VM? If it is, then i do need to have a property within those VM's that will hold the current instance of the "user" object? Am I understanding you correctly?

Comment: @Mike Yep, you've got it right. Pass the object on the ctor, then assign it to a member variable, and expose it via a public property with a getter so that you can bind it in the UI.

Comment: My apologies in advance if i over architect things or complicating it too much. Given the said approach, that would mean that every VM will have a property let's say "CurrentUser". Somehow does this violate the DRY principle?

Comment: @Mike Nope, because you would put the CurrentUser property into a base VM class that the client related VMs all inherit from.

Comment: If the CurrentUser property is into a base VM i.e. MainWindowViewModel, how can I access it from the other VM? Sorry I think I got a little confused here.

Comment: You need to check out the basics of OO inheritance: create a base viewmodel, call it something like BaseClientViewModel, it contains the common client related properties, then each client related viewmodel can inherit from it, so EditClientViewModel would inherit from BaseClientViewModel.

Comment: Oh Yes I get it now. Sorry I was over thinking it. Yes you are right. I use same approach in "paging"/navigating my application. I have a base model for "paging". Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Don't tie a current user to a ViewModel. I typically opt for a SessionService of some kind. If you're using Dependency Injection (DI), register a singleton of an ISessionService and concrete implementation. If your not using DI, then just have your app start create a singleton, like a SessionService.Current. Then you can put any items you need in here. Then each ViewModel can ask for the SessionService.Current.User and they have it. Your ViewModels shouldn't know about each other, but they can know about services. This keeps it DRY and loosely coupled, especially if you only access these session variables using the interface of an ISessionService and not the concrete implementation. This allows you to mock one up very easily without changing any ViewModel code.

Comment: Hi, can you kindly point me to an example on how to do this please? Forgive my ignorance but I have no idea on what you just said.

Comment: I use Prism and highly recommend reading this from Microsoft: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg406140.aspx. This is how to use Prism and helped me out a lot in structuring MVVM apps. For Dependency Injection, I use SimpleInjector a lot https://simpleinjector.org/, and I've just started using Unity since it's backed by MS. http://unity.codeplex.com/.  Simple injector has some great documentation on building services and mock services. Once you can separate out the logic into services, any DI library will work, but these two seem to be the best right now.

Comment: In which world is a service locator/static singleton accessor loosely coupled? Service locator isn't the alternative to DI, in fact it violates MVVM pattern. You were probably to say "If not using a DI, pass the instances to the constructor yourself". In MVVM IoC is actually mandatory, everything else violates the decoupling paradigm. However you can opt-out using IoC container. IoC Container != IoC, don't forget that. IoC can be done without an DI/IoC container.

Comment: @Tseng, I did not mean to suggest that without DI, a singleton is the only way.  I completely agree that a container is not needed and DI can be done without a container.  This should be strived for and then adding a container such as Unity or SimpleInjector will just ease the process immensely.

Answer (score 1):

What you have here is the problem of Communication between ViewModels. There are a number of solutions but my fave is the Mediator Pattern:

```
using System;

namespace UnitTestProject2
{
    public class GetDataViewModel
    {
        IMediator mediator;
        public GetDataViewModel(IMediator mediator)
        {
            this.mediator = mediator;
            this.mediator.ListenFor("LoggedIn", LoggedIn);
        }
        protected string UserId;
        protected void LoggedIn(Object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            UserId = sender.ToString();
        }
    }

    public class LoginViewModel
    {
        IMediator mediator;
        public LoginViewModel(IMediator mediator)
        {
            this.mediator = mediator;
        } 

        public string UserId { get; set; }
        public void Login(string userid)
        {
            this.UserId = userid;
            this.mediator.RaiseEvent("LoggedIn", this.UserId);
        }
    }

    public interface IMediator
    {
        public void ListenFor(string eventName, EventHandler action );
        public void RaiseEvent(string eventName, object data);
    }
}
```

I Haven't implemented the Mediator here, because it can get quite involved and there are a number of packages available. but you can see the idea from my simple interface. Essentially the Mediator provides a Global list of EventHandlers which any Viewmodel can call or add to. You still have the problem of where to store the event names. Its nice to have these in enums, but that gives you a coupling problem. (a problem I usually ignore)

Alternatively you can have a Controller or (MasterViewModel if you love MVVM)

```
using System;

namespace UnitTestProject3
{
    public class GetDataViewModel
    {
        protected string UserId;
        public void LoggedIn(Object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            UserId = sender.ToString();
        }
    }

    public class LoginViewModel
    {
        public EventHandler OnLogin;
        public string UserId { get; set; }
        public void Login(string userid)
        {
            this.UserId = userid;
            if (this.OnLogin != null)
            {
                this.OnLogin(this.UserId, null);
            }
        }
    }

    public class Controller // or MasterViewModel
    {
        public void SetUp()
        {
            GetDataViewModel vm1 = new GetDataViewModel();
            LoginViewModel vm2 = new LoginViewModel();
            vm2.OnLogin += vm1.LoggedIn;

            //wire up to views and display
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: event handlers are tight coupling. Loose coupling is achieved by using Event Aggregator/Messanger  injected into the ViewModels

Comment: hmm. well it tightly couples the controller to the vms. But this logic is inherrently part of your app. even if you use the mediator pattern I suggest you have to pass in the event name to listen for. In my view tight coupling of the application to its VMs is ok (although you can go via an interface to reduce it) the bad thing is tight coupling of vm1 to vm2 as this prevents reuse

Comment: in my usage here the controller is essentialy throwaway setup or configuration code. I want to use vm X, view Y, repository Z and connect them together in a specific way. Potentialy you can do this with sufficently complex IoC configuration. But in my view at some point configuration reaches a level of complexity where it is equivilant to coding

Comment: Yea, but you still need a reference to VM2 at one point or another. With mediator you don't need this reference. This above may work fine in a one-assembly app, but if you have modules? vm1 may be in one module, vm2 may be in second module and modules are dynamically loaded, so you have no reference to the VM itself in your "controller".

Comment: No in that case you would presumably have an interface Ivm2. I guess my point is that at some point you have to setup button vm1.A triggers event vm2.B. at that point I would contend that going fully non-coupled and passing strings around and hoping you don't get overlaps has more disadvantages than referencing types or interfaces. Although as I say, personally I DO pass in strings! i just know its evil

Comment: Never claimed you need strings. You can still have decoupled messaging without strings. You can create a `UserChangedEvent` class (implementation depends on your mediator framework) and pass the user within it. vm2: `mediator.Subscribe<UserChangedEvent>(OnUserChanged)`, vm1: `mediator.Publish<UserChangedEvent>(new UserChangedEvent() { User = newUser } )`. But that shoots a bit over it. The real question is, does the View really need to be aware of the User context or not or if user the passed services should be user aware (i.e. using IoC child containers for example, one per user)

Comment: its the same problem of what assembly do you put UserChangedEvent in. you can get around it by passing a string or object but then you code can error if you wire it up wrong

Comment: You usually have an assembly which is shared among all modules, i.e. "MyProject.Shared.dll". It contains all the interfaces which the modules and main application implement. So the modules can reference this interfaces and events, without knowing which modules implements them and still have it strongly typed. The strong typed events are your module contracts, which should be well defined and the modules should only use this well defined contracts to communicate with each other.

Comment: well exactly, and then your vms are all tightly coupled to the shared dll. having the controller wire up the events is less coupled

Comment: Which is the point of it, since you can't use Dependency Injection otherwise because you need the Interfaces. Interfaces are per assembly and if you define the same interface in multiple assemblies, it's still different interfaces and DI won't work outside of the module

Comment: maybe you should post an answer showing how you manage to achieve strongly typed events with less coupling than my Controller example